# Getting "No such file or directory" error in simple perl Dancer app

Tags: perl, dancer

Following the 'dwimmer' tutorial for Perl Dancer:
http://perlmaven.com/building-a-blog-engine-using-perl-dancer

But I'm getting a run time error:

> write_file '' - sysopen: No such file or directory

```
Here is the app.pl:

package miniblog;
use Dancer ':syntax';
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    template 'index';
};

get '/page' => sub {
    template 'page';
};

post '/page' => sub {
    my $file = config->{miniblog} {json};
    my $json = -e $file ? read_file $file : '{}';
    my $data = from_json $json;

    my $now = time;
    $data->{$now} = {
        title => params->{title},
        text => params->{text},
};
    write_file $file, to_json $data;
    redirect '/';

};

true;
```

Also here is the portion of the config.yaml file:

```
    template: "template_toolkit"
# engines:
template_toolkit:
encoding: 'utf8'
#     start_tag: '[%'
#     end_tag:   '%]'

miniblog: 
json: /home/rocko/Dancer_Projects/miniblog/miniblog.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Indenting is always important, but it's particularly important in YAML. Your bad indenting makes your code hard to read, and it's makes your YAML different than intended.

Change

```
    template: "template_toolkit"
# engines:
template_toolkit:
encoding: 'utf8'
#     start_tag: '[%'
#     end_tag:   '%]'

miniblog: 
json: /home/rocko/Dancer_Projects/miniblog/miniblog.jsonto
```

to

```
template: "template_toolkit"

template_toolkit:
     encoding:    'utf8'
     # start_tag: '[%'
     # end_tag:   '%]'

miniblog: 
    json: /home/rocko/Dancer_Projects/miniblog/miniblog.jsonto
```